# Why is is not possible to test anything other than a boolean?

Tags: java, boolean

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why boolean in Java takes only true or false? Why not 1 or 0 also?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2015071/why-boolean-in-java-takes-only-true-or-false-why-not-1-or-0-also)

I was wondering today why Java cannot test any other type than a boolean.

In C, C++ and many other languages (actually most programming languages), the following is possible and valid:

```
int a = 0;
if (a) // evaluates to false
  ; // do something nice

a = 6;
if (a) // evaluates to true
  ; // do something more
```

This also works almost everywhere for objects, arrays; anything that can have a value of `0x00000000` in the memory.

The question: why is this not possible in Java (you have to keep on testing for `== 0` or `== null`)?

Comment: Because that's how Java is. I'd also posit that an if statement is intrinsically boolean by nature, a number isn't really boolean, hence using a number as a boolean wouldn't really be considered type-appropriate.

Comment: Because it is meaningless to evaluate anything other than a boolean in an `if` condition.

Comment: C/C++ supports more implied casts between the base types

Comment: (FWIW, I've added a new answer to the linked question ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess that the rationale why is because it simplifies things.

An if statement has to evaluate a value to one of two possible conditions. What Java does is require you to supply a statement itself that must evaluate to two possible conditions (boolean) rather than accept other values and arbitrarily decide if that evaluates to true or false.

Answer (score 0):

Because James Gosling *et al* decided that Java wouldn't do that.