# Android,Use switch case is used to determine the boolean

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement

I'm writing some programs.Im going to use this programs to tell the situation of the connection.
I would only use if-else, and now I want to learn how to use switch case,but I found switch case 
dont use boolean,The following is what I wrote judgment formula:

```css
if(isConnected) {
    //if connection established 
    btnwifi.setText("Connection");
} else {  
    btnwifi.setText("Unconnected");
}
```

Comment: switch does not allow long, float, double or boolean values in Java! You can use enum if a variable can take two or more values.. For boolean's if else is better.

Comment: Extended on @MohammedAli you can't do switch on any primitives. Enums were worked into switches and allow more explicit declarations.

Comment: Enums are best used with switch. And also see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5141830/switch-expression-cant-be-float-double-or-boolean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want learn switch.
You can use enums for your purpose,

```
public enum BtnWifi { // you can create new enum java file for this
 CONNECTED, NOT_CONNECTED
}
//.... Setting value for enum in your code
BtnWifi btnWifi;
if(isConnected) {
//if connection established 
   btnWifi = BtnWifi.CONNECTED;
} else {     
   btnWifi = BtnWifi.NOT_CONNECTED;
}
// No switch to use it...
switch(btnWifi) {
  case CONNECTED:
     //code for connected...
   break;
  case NOT_CONNECTED:
     //code for Not connected...
   break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you want to implement it this way. See link for  boolean type in java [why java takes only true of false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2015071/why-boolean-in-java-takes-only-true-or-false-why-not-1-or-0-also)

For switch, you may refer to this [oracle doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)

if you are so into switch, create a function which converts a boolean type to static constants of byte, short, char, int or string type and then use that in your switch statement though i won't recommend doing so.

Answer (score 0):

This is not what `switch` is intended for and is not supported in Java.

The `if` statement is used to control program flow based on boolean values and works perfectly, so why try to use something else?  If you want to learn about `switch` statements your first port of call would be to learn where they are, and are not meaningful!