# Cant convert int to boolean for while loop

Tags: java

```
package homeWork;

import java.util.*;

public class MainClass {

public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner conIn = new Scanner(System.in);
    ShoppingBag sb = new ShoppingBag(0.06f);
    int count = 0;
    float cost = 0.0f;
    System.out.print("Enter count (0 to stop):");
    count = conIn.nextInt();

    while(count){
        System.out.print("Enter cost: ");
        cost = conIn.nextFloat();
        sb.place(count, cost);
        System.out.print("Enter count (0 to stop):");
        count = conIn.nextInt();
    }

}

}
```

I get an error for the while loop and cannot run the program. When I tried converting count to boolean everything got wonky. Not sure what my best course of action should be.

Comment: You need to have a boolean condition in the loop and not a number

Comment: You should bother to look up a problem before you post  it on S.O.

Comment: Java does not take anything thats not zero like C++.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2015071/why-boolean-in-java-takes-only-true-or-false-why-not-1-or-0-also

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Different from other programming languages (such as C), java only accepts boolean expressions at loop control.
  Then you should do something like as:

```
//prev code
while(count != 0){
    //your loop
}
```

Answer (score 0):

syntax for while:

```
while(condition)
{
    //statements
}
```

for your question
have a increment variable i

```
while(count<i)
{
    //code
    i++;
}
```