# Java - error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to boolean

Tags: java, types, boolean

Considering operation: (7>>1)&1

When we put into print statement it works:
***System.out.println((7>>1)&1);**  // works*

But if we put in if condition there is error:

**if((7>>1)&1) System.out.println('Here');**  # shows error

> error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to boolean
> if((7>>1)&1) System.out.println(123);

I am unable to understand what could be the issue? Since same works in C++..

I tried assigning to a variable
int a=(7>>1)&1

if(a==1) System.out.println('works');  // it works here but not when passed directly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As SmallPepperZ stated, in java, `if` statements do not accept any argument except the `boolean` primitive type, or a statement that can be evaluated to the `boolean` primitive type.

To expand on SmallPepperZ answer, the reason for your second issue, requiring that the variable `a` be used, is due to the fact that the expression gets evaluated in the following way:

```
if( (7>>1)&1 == 1 )
if( 3 & 1 == 1 )
if( 3 & true )
```

The error you would have seen should have been the following:

```
The operator & is undefined for the argument type(s) int, boolean
```

To fix this, add a set of parenthesis around the expression on the left

```
if( ((7>>1)&1) == 1 ) System.out.println("Here");
```

which gets evaluated in the following way:

```
if( ((7>>1)&1) == 1 )
if( ((3)&1) == 1 )
if( (3&1) == 1 )
if( 1 == 1 )
if( true )
```

Answer (score 3):

Java does not interpret the integers `1` and `0` as equivalent to the booleans `true` and `false`, unlike C++

See [Why boolean in Java takes only true or false? Why not 1 or 0 also?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2015071/why-boolean-in-java-takes-only-true-or-false-why-not-1-or-0-also) for more information.